# Microsoft word is detecting spelling issues in US English only, and not UK English

Tags: microsoft-word, language, spell-check

I'm editing a document and it states there are 235 spelling issues under US English, but none for UK English.

I have checked, and these aren't simple differences in US/UK spelling, they are words simply spelt. incorrectly.

[image]

I checked in the language and proofing settings and made UK the preferred language, and even removed US, but still the issue persists.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on MS-Word, but don't you have to specifically [mark the *document* text as being English(UK)](https://proofreadmyessay.co.uk/writing-tips/change-language-document/) before Word will spell-check against a UK dictionary? Setting defaults in Word may have no effect on existing documents if Word thinks the *current document* is English(US) text.

> 1. Select all of the text in your document. To do this quickly, use ‘Ctrl + A’
> 2. go to the ‘Review’ tab, click ‘Language’ and select ‘Set Proofing Language’.

Comment: Thank you, that was it!

Strange, I've been using word for years with both US and UK language installed, and never had this issue until now.